# Actionscript 3 Password Verifier Doesn't Match Passwords

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on an flash password verification project where a user types in a password that's 6 to 10 characters and must contain one uppercase, one lowercase, and one number.

When I test the program and type in a password I get the "Passwords DID NOT MATCH. Try again." in the feedback_txt field.

I have two functions that are called by the Submit button’s event handler: Same() and PasswordApproved(). The Same function verifies the password was entered both times. The PasswordApproved function verifies that the password meets specified standards.

I was giving a tip to use CharCodeAt to help with the PasswordApproved part, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Here's the Code:

```
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Submit);
function Submit(e:MouseEvent):void {
var pass1:String = password1_txt.text;
var pass2:String = password2_txt.text;
if (Same(pass1,pass2) == true) {
if (PasswordApproved(pass1) == true)  {
        feedback_txt.text = "Your password was APPROVED."
        feedback_txt.textColor = 0x00FF00;
} else {
        feedback_txt.text = "DID NOT MEET QUALIFICATIONS. Try again."
        feedback_txt.textColor = 0xFF0000;
}
} else {
    feedback_txt.text = "Passwords DID NOT MATCH. Try again."
    feedback_txt.textColor = 0xFF0000;
}
password1_txt.text = "";
password2_txt.text = "";
stage.focus = password1_txt;
}
```

This is what I have for the functions (I think this is the reason why it's not working. I'm not writing it correctly? or it's just wrong) :

```
function Same(pass1,pass2:String):void {
var pass1:String = password1_txt.text;
var pass2:String = password2_txt.text;
}


function PasswordApproved(pass1:String):String {
var pass1:String = "abchefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM0123456789";
var i:Number = 0;
var pass:String = "";
var nLength:Number = pass1.length;
var length:Number = 10
while(i<=length) 
{
    var num:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * nLength);
    pass += pass1.charCodeAt(num);
    i++;
}
return pass;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you're trying to do using one single `if` statement and one [`RegExp`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) object, like this for example :

```
var password_pattern:RegExp = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,10}$/; 
//                               │       │          │          │    
//                               │       │          │          └─> from 6 to 10 chars
//                               │       │          │
//                               │       │          └─> at least one upper letter
//                               │       │
//                               │       └─> at least one lower letter
//                               │
//                               └──> at least one digit

if(password1_txt.text == password2_txt.text && password_pattern.test(password1_txt.text)) {
    trace('Your password was APPROVED.');
} else {
    trace('Your password was NOT APPROVED.');
}
```

For more about using regular expressions, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdb.html).

**Edit :**

To use your `Same` function correctly, you've to give it a type, in your case it's `Boolean` and then return the comparison result like this :

```
function Same(pass1, pass2:String): Boolean 
{
    return pass1 == pass2;
}
```

**Edit 2 :**

Your `PasswordApproved()` function can only verify your password because you've already verify that both passwords are the same. So it can be like this :

```
function PasswordApproved(pass:String):Boolean 
{
    var password_pattern:RegExp = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,10}$/;
    return password_pattern.test(pass);
}
```

then you can call it :

```
if (Same(pass1, pass2)) {               // the same as : Same(pass1, pass2) == true
    if (PasswordApproved(pass1))  {     // the same as : PasswordApproved(pass1) == true
        feedback_txt.text = "Your password was APPROVED."
        feedback_txt.textColor = 0x00FF00;
    } else {
        feedback_txt.text = "DID NOT MEET QUALIFICATIONS. Try again."
        feedback_txt.textColor = 0xFF0000;
    }
} else {
    feedback_txt.text = "Passwords DID NOT MATCH. Try again."
    feedback_txt.textColor = 0xFF0000;
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but i'm still getting the "Passwords DID NOT MATCH. Try again."   I posted the rest of my code, but I think the Same function is the reason why it's not working. Is there a way for me to make sure both passwords match?

Comment: @Tams As I've already mentioned, you don't even need the `Same` function because you verify that your text fields are the same using that `if` statement, but if you like always using it, I'll edit my answer to correct it for you.

Comment: Thank you, akmozo. I tested and everything is working fine now.

Comment: @Tams In that case, if my post was what you are looking for, you can select it as accepted answer.

Comment: I know this is a late reply, but I was working on this project again & noticed that it seems to approve any password as long as they match.  I only need approve passwords that are between 6 &10 character in length & contain at least one number, one UPPERCASE character, and one lowercase character. I've tried everything to fix this but nothing I do seems to work.

Comment: I think the regex is fine but I'm not sure why it's approving passwords that are not between 6 to 10 characters. If I type "cats" its approved which it shouldn't because it doesn't meet the qualifications.

Comment: @Tams Could you show me your whole code using [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) for example ...

Comment: Thanks again, akmozo! everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting the `Same` function to do?

```
function Same(pass1,pass2:String):void {
var pass1:String = password1_txt.text;
var pass2:String = password2_txt.text;
}
```

This function returns `void`, meaning it doesn't do much when you then write something like

```
if (Same(pass1,pass2) == true) {
```

Because that will never be the case.